# Energy Flux Through Horizon

Tags: general-relativity, field-theory, gauss-law, classical-field-theory, kerr-metric

In Kerr spacetime, given the energy-momentum tensor $T^{ab}$ of a field, what is the energy flux (as measured at infinity)
$$
\frac{d^2E}{dt d\Omega}
$$
i.e., the amount of energy passing through the horizon per unit time and solid angle (in Boyer-Lindquist coordinate)? Or the total flux?

I know $j^\mu=T^\mu_0$ is a conserved current ($\nabla_\mu j^\mu=0$), but how exactly can this be related to the energy flux?

Comment: *In Kerr spacetime, given the energy-momentum tensor $T^{ab}$ of a field* … You already lost me. Kerr spacetime is a vacuum solution, it has $T^{ab}\equiv 0$. Do you mean that there is a “test” field on Kerr background that does not modify geometry, or something else?

Comment: @A.V.S. yeah, assuming it's a test field, in a fixed Kerr background. Then I suppose the flux is well-defined?

Comment: Where can I find discussions of this?

Comment: Have you looked at discussion in Wald's GR book at p. 328?

Comment: @A.V.S. thanks! this is what I need. So the flux is $j^\mu n_\mu$ where $n^\mu$ is the normal vector $n^\mu=-(1,0,0,\Omega_H)$. still I don't quite understand why $n^\mu$ has this specific normalization, since it's null. Is it fixed by requiring the definition of energy is consistent with observer at inifinity?